# Samba share on my Arch Linux server unreachable after a couple of hours

Tags: arch-linux, samba, smb

I'm running a samba share on an Arch Linux server for two years now, I never had any problems with it. But for a month now, the samba share becomes unreachable after a couple of hours. It started happening around the time I received a new router from my ISP, don't now if that can be the cause.

Restarting the smb.service and nmb.service doesn't work. Only a reboot solves the problem.

The 'journalctl -xe' logs don't show something special.

I'm a bit lost where to search and could use some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify "becomes unreachable". Does the connection report a server-side error? Do you become unable to connect to the share by IP address:port (`\\192.168.x.y\myshare` or `nc -vv 192.168.x.y 445`)? Do you become unable to connect to the share by NetBIOS hostname? Do you lose the share from the Windows "Network computers" list?

Comment: The connection doesn't report an error, it just times out. Currently the smb share is working, so I'll post the output when the problem occurs again. The share becomes unreachable by both NetBIOS and IP. It's still listed though in my Network Computers list.

Comment: Does the server become unreachable in general, or only on tcp/445 (the SMB port)? Does it have a firewall configured? Can you use tcpdump or Wireshark to check whether it's still receiving the packets from clients?

Comment: Only smb. I can still access the server using SSH, and other network services also keep working just fine. There is no firewall enabled. The problems started to happen out of nowhere, I didn't reconfigure something at the server around the days before or so. When it becomes unreachable again I'll posy the tcpdump output. Thanks for your help.